# Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos: Odin flashed the custom Recovery but device boots into stock Recovery

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, odin, samsung-galaxy-grand

I am new to rooting Android. I tried using Odin 3.10 to root my Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos. I successfully flashed CWM (Odin displayed pass message). However when I restart phone in Recovery mode, it shows Android with an error symbol, and then loads the stock Recovery.

I am trying to flash CM12. What's the issue, and how do I fix it because I want to root my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Before you flash the recovery, untick the **Auto Reboot** option in ODIN. Then flash the recovery. After flashing in done, reboot your device directly to recovery mode from download mode bu pressing **Vol up + Power + Home** button together. Now you will see the CWM recovery is booted in your device. Now you can reboot normally and your CWM will be installed.

Comment: The question is about CWM, not TWRP. This is the kind of mistake you'll make if you [paste your other answers](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/143691/12442) without paying attention.

Comment: sorry about the mistake. I will be more careful. But my answer is correct. This is the way to install custom recovery in samsung devices when this problem is occurred.