# After flashing TWRP with Odin, nothing happens and the OEM recovery is still there

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-s-5, odin

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S5, and after flashing the TWRP with Odin 3.07 and 3.10 I'm finding that my recovery is still the default. I'm using [these instructions](http://androiding.how/how-to-install-twrp-recovery-using-odin/) exactly.

> Android system Recovery <3e>

It's as if nothing happened, how do I resolve this?

Comment: I had to use the TWRP app installed from the app store, it has a reboot function that will restart the phone into the TWRP recovery which you ave flashed to the device. I had a SM-T535 that always went to stock recovery even though TWRP was flashed to it with Odin. Using the app helped in that I didn't have to fiddle with timing and button presses etc.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Before you flash the recovery, untick the **Auto Reboot** option in ODIN. Then flash the recovery. After flashing in done, reboot your device directly to recovery mode from download mode by pressing **Vol up + Power + Home** button together. Now you will see the TWRP recovery is booted in your device. Now you can reboot normally and your TWRP will be installed.

Comment: For older Samsungs (e.g. the Trend ST-5760 and Duos ST-5762), download mode is VolUp+VolDown+Power+Home

Comment: battery pull actually solved my problem.

Comment: my device does not have a removable battery (J5 2017). pressing on Vol up + Power + Home while I'm in recovery mode doesn't do anything. Any other suggestions? (Same comment below, sorry for being redundant)

Comment: @AndyWeinstein With auto reboot disabled you don't have to remove the battery. On my Edge 7 I waited for Odin to finish and then pressed *Volume **Down** + Power + Home* to shutdown and then *Volume **Up** + Power + Home*  to boot into TWRP

Comment: Fantastic! It worked! Let me expand on the previous comment for anyone who didn't understand it, (I didn't).You don't really need to remove the battery. When you uncheck that "auto-reboot" option in odin and then shutdown the phone (Same key combination which allowed you to start download-mode in the first place) then it will not auto-reboot. Which means at that point you can press the key combination to enter recovery mode and you should reach twrp.

Comment: Worked even for Note8 :)

Comment: This is actually mentioned on the TWRP page (for my old Samsung Galaxy Tab 4: `Note many devices will replace your custom recovery automatically during first boot. To prevent this, use Google to find the proper key combo to enter recovery. After typing fastboot reboot, hold the key combo and boot to TWRP. Once TWRP is booted, TWRP will patch the stock ROM to prevent the stock ROM from replacing TWRP. If you don't follow this step, you will have to repeat the install.` (from https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxytab4101.html)

Comment: This hasn't worked for me; pressing volume up, home and power together hangs before the phone gets to recovery

Answer (score 10):

[Per this page](http://www.epiccm.org/2012/06/cwm-recovery-on-all-sgs3-lte-variants.html),

> WARNING: Do not boot into Samsung's ROM without first applying our Root .zip.  **Samsung's OTA updates install /system/etc/install-recovery.sh and /system/recovery-from-boot.p, which cause Samsung's ROM to replace the recovery image you had just flashed with the stock recovery.**  Our Root .zip removes these files, thus preserving your custom recovery.  Follow the directions below to boot directly into CWM recovery.

Which is good information because it's telling you exactly what happening. **However, you can get around this without downloading their questionable files:** After you install the TWRP Recovery with Odin the device will reboot. After it vibrates in the rebooting process, pull the battery. Have it ready to pull, it boots fast.

Pop the battery back back in, and hold your recovery sequence (Vol Up+Home+Power). This will get you into the TWRP, and you can now sideload, or if that fails `adb push $file /data/` the files you want to install.

Comment: my device does not have a removable battery (J5 2017). pressing on Vol up + Power + Home while I'm in recovery mode doesn't do anything. Any other suggestions?