# Reinstalling TWRP via Odin on Android 4.1, failed after "SetupConnection"

Tags: samsung, 4.1-jelly-bean, twrp, odin, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I recently installed TWRP recovery into a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 GT-N8013 tablet running Android 4.1.1 via Odin. I wanted to install a custom ROM, in this case LineageOS. Unfortunately, I installed TWRP with the check box "Auto Reboot" ticked, this meant I could not boot the tablet into TWRP recovery mode; instead it booted with the default Android System Recovery.

I then read [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143685/after-flashing-twrp-with-odin-nothing-happens-and-the-oem-recovery-is-still-there) which provided the solution to this issue.

What I had to do was reinstall the same TWRP TAR file in the same method but with the aforementioned check box unticked. I employed the same methods but what it returned was:

```
<ID:0/003> Added!!
<ID:0/003> Odin engine v(ID:3.1203)..
<ID:0/003> File analysis..
<ID:0/003> SetupConnection..
```

5 to 10 minutes later...

```
<ID:0/003> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

I tried using a different TWRP TAR file but I gave me the same result.

How else should I reinstall TWRP and how should I install it correctly?

Comment: Odin does not understand `.zip` files. You need to feed it the TWRP `.img`

Comment: I was mistaken with the file extensions. I'll edit the question now. Also, I am not familiar with flashing in IMG format. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using the correct version of TWRP solved the issue. In this case, it was [`twrp-2.8.6.0-gt-n8013.tar`](https://dl.twrp.me/p4noterf/twrp-2.8.6.0-gt-n8013.tar.html).**

In my previous attempts, I had used the incorrect versions of TWRP for my specific device: [`twrp-2.8.6.0-p4notewifi.tar`](https://dl.twrp.me/p4noterf/twrp-2.8.6.0-p4notewifi.tar.html) and [`twrp-3.0.2-0-lt03wifiue.img.tar`](https://dl.twrp.me/lt03wifiue/twrp-3.0.2-0-lt03wifiue.img.tar.html).