# samsung odin twrp recovery

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, twrp, odin

I have exactly the same problem of this question:
[After flashing TWRP with Odin, nothing happens and the OEM recovery is still there](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143685/after-flashing-twrp-with-odin-nothing-happens-and-the-oem-recovery-is-still-the?newreg=730ba4a05f8e4e2281546bf5fa6332cd)

The problem is the answer is not valid for me, my volume buttons don't work.
Is there another way to do it without using vol+?

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you can still boot the phone like normal since your question did not specify if it could or could not boot.

- boot the phone normally
- enable USB debugging
- connect to computer by cable
- from the computer, run adb reboot recovery
- phone reboots directly to recovery

Done!